# Access instance of a sister class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a struct with three classes as members, and for my idea to work I want instances of my classes to be able to access instances of sisters within one struct. So let's say after initializing `struct`, I want my `custom_class_one` to be able to call methods of initialized `sister custom_class_two`. Is it even possible to do it? Here's my header file:

```
struct custom_wrapper
{
public:
    custom_wrapper();

    class custom_class_one
    {
    private:
        int number1;
    public:
        int getNumber1();
    };

   class custom_class_two
    {
    private:
        int number2;
    public:
        int getNumber2();
    };

    class custom_class_three
    {
    private:
        int number3;
    public:
        int getNumber3();
    };
```

};

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to demonstrate how you intend to use your inner classes. A class is a type, and non-static methods need to be invoked against an instance.

Comment: Where's your sense of adventure? Try it. See if it works. If something doesn't work that you think should work, ask here with the details. If something works that you think shouldn't work, once again, ask here with details.

Comment: BTW, C++ has member functions.  Under certain circumstances which do not apply in your example, they can gain most of the semantics of CS-theoretic methods.

Comment: I am having troubles with calling child constructors from parent constructor, I want to initialize all three children when parent is created.

Comment: Why is the declaration of `custom_class_one`, `custom_class_two` and `custom_class_three` nested in `custom_wrapper`? Is there any difference between `custom_class_one`, `custom_class_two` and `custom_class_three` other than their names? When you say "instances of sisters *within* one struct" are you talking about *composition*, i.e a *has-a* relationship because I see no composition in your question.

Comment: They are different, i just simplified it just to get basic idea of how it works, and you are right - i am talking about "has a" relationship,  how can i do a composition?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your methods are accessible and the classes can see each other (forward declaring if needed), it can be done:

```
struct custom_wrapper
{
public:
    custom_wrapper();

    class custom_class_two; // Forward declaration for inner class

    class custom_class_one
    {
    private:
        int number1;
    public:
        int getNumber1();
        int accessSisterMethods(custom_class_two& obj) {
         return obj.getNumber2();   
        }
    };

   class custom_class_two
    {
    private:
        int number2;
    public:
        int getNumber2() {
            return 42;
        }
    };

    class custom_class_three
    {
    private:
        int number3;
    public:
        int getNumber3();
    };
};


int main()
{
    custom_wrapper::custom_class_one obj1;
    custom_wrapper::custom_class_two obj2; // Need a sister object

    std::cout << obj1.accessSisterMethods(obj2);
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/e3aDO4)</kbd>

Of course you need an **instance** of the other sister class (unless you're calling static methods, but I'm considering the code you posted).

Comment: In some cases it may also be necessary to use out-of-line function definitions.

Comment: Thank you, it is still unclear, but at least I have a dim idea of what to do! Could you also post how to call child's constructor in parent constructor?

Comment: I'd experiment that myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think you are confusing a few concepts here: *composition*, *nested classes*, *instances*. Or I'm misunderstanding your question and will delete/edit my answer.

When you say "instances of sisters *within* one struct" I think you are really looking for composition. As in a *has-a* relationship. You don't need to have nested classes to have composition. For composition you need member variables.

Perhaps what you really want is something like this, correct me if I'm wrong:

```
struct CustomClassA {
 private:
  int number;
 public:
  int getNumber() { return number; }
};

struct CustomClassB {
 private:
  int number;
 public:
  int getNumber() { return number; }
};

struct CustomClassC {
 private:
  int number;
 public:
  int getNumber() { return number; }
};

struct CustomWrapper {
 private:
  CustomClassA a;
  CustomClassB b;
  CustomClassC c;
};
```

So, if you create an instance of a `CustomWrapper` it *has* instances of the custom classes, `a`, `b` and `c`. It "owns" them.

And then you want the three custom classes to be able to communicate with each other. There are number of ways of achieving that. The custom classes could have pointers to the other sister classes. These could be set in the constructor of `CustomWrapper`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct CustomClassB;  // Forward declaration for member pointer in CustomClassA.

struct CustomClassA {
 private:
  int           number;
  CustomClassB* b;  // Member pointer to CustomClassB.
 public:
  CustomClassA() : number(1), b(nullptr) {}  // Initialized sister b to nullptr.
  void setSisterB(CustomClassB *sister_b) { b = sister_b; }
  int  getNumber() { return number; }
};

struct CustomClassB {
 private:
  int           number;
  CustomClassA* a;
 public:
  CustomClassB() : number(2), a(nullptr) {}
  void setSisterA(CustomClassA *sister_a) { a = sister_a; }

  int  getNumber() {
    if (a)  // Check a is not null
      return a->getNumber() + number; // Use pointer to sister a 
    return number; 
  }
};

struct CustomClassC {
 private:
  int           number;
  CustomClassA* a;
  CustomClassB* b;
 public:
  CustomClassC() : number(4), a(nullptr), b(nullptr) {} 
  void setSisterA(CustomClassA* sister_a) { a = sister_a; }
  void setSisterB(CustomClassB* sister_b) { b = sister_b; }
  int  getNumber() { return number; }
};

struct CustomWrapper {
 private:
  CustomClassA a;
  CustomClassB b;
  CustomClassC c;
 public:
  CustomWrapper() {
    a.setSisterB(&b);  // Set the pointers to the sister custom
    b.setSisterA(&a);  // classes in each custom class in the 
    c.setSisterA(&a);  // constructor of CustomWrapper.
    c.setSisterB(&b);
  }
  int getAnswer() {
    return b.getNumber() + c.getNumber();
  }
};

int main() {
  CustomWrapper wrapper;
  std::cout << wrapper.getAnswer();
}
```

Or the custom classes could have a pointer to the custom wrapper and communicate with their sisters via the wrapper.